Windows API ISimpleAudioVolume GetMasterVolume not working
I'm trying to mess with the audio API for a pet project of mine. I can't seem to get the volume for the sessions.
I managed to get the default endpoint calling GetDefaultAudioEndpoint on a device enumerator.
I managed to get a IAudioEndpointVolume object to get the master volume and change it at will.
I'm trying to get the volume for each audio session using windows API.
I get a IAudioSessionManager2 then a SessionEnumerator, the session enumerator return a audioSessionControl that I use to get a simpleAudioVolume.
The simple audio volume, allows me to set the volume for the session but the GetMasterVolume returns 0.00.
Here is the code:
void PrintEndpointNames() {
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator = NULL;
    IMMDeviceCollection* pCollection = NULL;
    IMMDevice* pEndpoint = NULL;
    IPropertyStore* pProps = NULL;
    IAudioSessionManager2* pAudioSessionManager = NULL;
    IAudioSessionEnumerator* pSessionEnumerator = NULL;
    IAudioSessionManager2* pSessionManager = NULL;
    IAudioEndpointVolume* ppInterface = NULL;
    float volume = NULL;
    PROPVARIANT id;
    PROPVARIANT varName;
    float pflVolumeMindB = NULL;
    float pflVolumeMaxdB = NULL;
    float pflVolumeIncrementdB = NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator),
        (void**)&pEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    // Get the default audio endpoint
    hr = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &pEndpoint);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);


    hr = pEndpoint->OpenPropertyStore(
            STGM_READ, &pProps);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    PropVariantInit(&varName);
    // Get the endpoint's friendly-name property.
    hr = pProps->GetValue(
        PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &varName);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    // GetValue succeeds and returns S_OK if PKEY_Device_FriendlyName is not found.
    // In this case vartName.vt is set to VT_EMPTY.      
    if (varName.vt != VT_EMPTY)
    {
        // Print endpoint friendly name and endpoint ID.
        printf("Endpoint : \"%S\"\n", varName.pwszVal);
    }

    //Get audio client
    pEndpoint->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&ppInterface);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    ppInterface->GetVolumeRange(&pflVolumeMindB, &pflVolumeMaxdB, &pflVolumeIncrementdB);
    std::cout << "    Volume range : min:" << pflVolumeMindB << "dB, max:" << pflVolumeMaxdB << "dB increment:" << pflVolumeIncrementdB << "dB" << std::endl;
    ppInterface->GetMasterVolumeLevel(&volume);
    printf("    CurrentVolume %f\n", volume);

    // Get the IAudioSessionManager2 interface
    hr = pEndpoint->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioSessionManager);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    // Enumerate audio sessions
    hr = pAudioSessionManager->GetSessionEnumerator(&pSessionEnumerator);
    EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

    int sessionCount;
    hr = pSessionEnumerator->GetCount(&sessionCount);
    std::cout << "    " << sessionCount << " sessions :" << std::endl;

    // Looping over the sessions
    for (int i = 0; i < sessionCount; i++) {
        IAudioSessionControl* pSessionControl = NULL;
        hr = pSessionEnumerator->GetSession(i, &pSessionControl);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

        IAudioSessionControl2* pSessionControl2 = NULL;
        pSessionControl->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IAudioSessionControl2), (void**)&pSessionControl2);
        EXIT_ON_ERROR(hr, __LINE__);

        float* pfLevel = NULL;
        ISimpleAudioVolume* pSimpleAudioVolume = NULL;
        hr = pSessionControl2->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISimpleAudioVolume), (void**)&pSimpleAudioVolume);

        pSimpleAudioVolume->GetMasterVolume(pfLevel);
        printf("    ----[%d] Vol:%f\n", i+1, pfLevel);
        pSessionControl->Release();
    }

    PropVariantClear(&varName);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pProps)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pEndpoint)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
        SAFE_RELEASE(pCollection)
        return;

Exit:
    printf("Error!\n");
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pCollection)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEndpoint)
    SAFE_RELEASE(pProps)
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    PrintEndpointNames();
    return 0;
}


It should be float pfLevel, and you should retrieve it using &pfLevel - you're not actually retrieving the level properly.

I can't believe I missed it soo many times ! Thank you it's working now !

As Anya Shenanigans pointed out
changing the code like this solved my issue
    float pfLevel = NULL;
    pSimpleAudioVolume->GetMasterVolume(&pfLevel);

